# How to create test bucket before running tests by django-minio-backend

Tags: django, django-testing, django-settings, minio

I use [`django-minio-backend`](https://pypi.org/project/django-minio-backend/) in order to integrate Django and Minio.
I want to create a test bucket for created media files during tests running.

I tried to do that in a custom test runner as follows:

```
class CoreTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):

    def setup_test_environment(self, **kwargs):
        super(CoreTestRunner, self).setup_test_environment()
        self._make_test_file_storage()

    def _make_test_file_storage(self):
        minio_test_bucket = "test-bucket"
        settings.MINIO_MEDIA_FILES_BUCKET = minio_test_bucket
        settings.MINIO_PRIVATE_BUCKETS = [minio_test_bucket]
        call_command("initialize_buckets")
```

The problem is that when I run the test command, Minio creates the `test-bucket`, but uploads all files to the old bucket (the available bucket before creating `test-bucket`)
The old bucket in `settings.py` is `project-media-bucket` and all the files are uploaded in this bucket instead of uploading on `test-bucket`.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change the Django settings during runtime? That may not work. Take a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime).

Can you add these settings to the settings.py and in your tests you can create bucket during init and delete after each test runner is done?